# How to import Palette.Builder android - AppCompat, Eclipse

Tags: android, android-palette

I have the following code for Palette, which gets the DarkMutedColor and sets to the background of my textView.

```
    Palette.generateAsync(response.getBitmap(),
        new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {

            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                holder.title.setBackgroundColor(
                        palette.getDarkMutedColor(
                                Color.parseColor(Const.ACTIONBAR_BACKGROUND)));

            }

        });
```

But, i recently came across Palette.Builder and wondering how to use it.

From Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.Builder.html):

> Instances are created with a Palette.Builder which supports several
>   options to tweak the generated Palette. See that class' documentation
>   for more information.
>
> Generation should always be completed on a background thread, ideally
>   the one in which you load your image on. Palette.Builder supports both
>   synchronous and asynchronous generation

But, i cant find any class named Builder, when i type, Palette(dot)? How do i import, Palette.Builder and its methods?

Comment: Have you tried writing `android.support.v7.graphics.Palette.Builder`?

Comment: I tried, but it says, android....Builder cannot be resolved.

Comment: If using Android Studio, please update your question with your gradle file. If using Eclipse, please check if AppCompat is added as library.

Comment: My targetSDKVersion is 21. I am using Eclipse. So, in order to use it, should my minSDKVersion be 21? Can you please point me to the source, where it says, its only available for API >=21.

Comment: It's not for API >= 21. Can you check first to make sure you have at least 22.1 version of the Android Support Library, and that your project is indeed referring to that version?

Comment: Yeah.. I updated my SDK, but i didn't update the .jar file in my project. That was the problem. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, update your SDK and update the previously used .jar file in your libs folder of the Main project.

And to use it:

```
    Palette.from(response.getBitmap()).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                        holder.title.setBackgroundColor(palette.getDarkMutedColor(Color
                                    .parseColor(Const.ACTIONBAR_BACKGROUND)));

                     }
});
```